# Doctrine Query calculate MAX value in WHERE clause

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I have this tables:

*subscribers*

```
id | name  |
---+-------+
1  | Hill  |
2  | Sam   |
3  | Joe   |
```

subscribers_years

```
subscriber_id | year  |
--------------+-------+
1             | 2009  |
1             | 2010  |
1             | 2011  |
2             | 2009  |
2             | 2010  |
3             | 2010  |
```

I want to take an advanced search using only records that have a maximum as x.
If x = 2010
Results query must be: Sam and Joe!

I try this:

```
$query = $this->createQuery('su')
            ->select('su.id, su.name)
            ->addWhere(
                '(SELECT MAX(year) AS maxYear FROM `subscribers_years` WHERE `subscriber_id`=`su.id`) = ?',
                2010
            );
```

but i have the message error: Message: Couldn't find class `subscribers_years`

how should I write my query right way?

---

### Solution

```
$query->addWhere('(SELECT MAX(year) AS maxYear FROM SubscriberYear WHERE subscriber_id=su.id) = ?', 2010 );
```

my mistake was that I did not use the class name Doctrine as the From, but used the name of the table mysql! :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have plain SQL in your doctrine subqueries. You have two choices:

1. Use the model name for `subscribers_years` table in your [subquery](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/pl/dql-doctrine-query-language%3asubqueries)
2. Use [RAW SQL](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/native-sql) in your query

If you don't need any advanced SQL I'd go with option 1, since it has less SQL and you don't need to specify join conditions otherwise you should use 2.

You can always add a Doctrine class for your `subscribers_years` if you don't have it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to go here is using `createSubquery()` to explicitly tell doctrine about the subquery, then nest it into the where condition. The pattern is pretty easy and can be used for any complexity. You query should then look something like this:

```
$query = $this->createQuery('su')
    ->select('su.id, su.name)
;

$subquery = $query->createSubquery()
    ->select("MAX(year) AS maxYear")
    ->from("SubscriberYear")
    ->where("subscriber_id=su.id")
;

$query->addWhere($subquery->getDql().' = ?', 2010 );
```

Here is another example for creating Subqueries:

http://www.philipphoffmann.de/2012/08/taming-doctrine-subqueries/